# Best practice for database structure (MongoDB)

Tags: database, mongodb, express, data-structures

I'm trying to learn the proper way to structure my database for a simple app and API using Express and MongoDB.

Let's say I have some CITIES and inside that there's some BUILDINGS and inside that there's some PROPERTIES.

Should I have a single CITIES collection with an array inside for BUILDINGS. Or should I have separate collections for CITIES, BUILDINGS and PROPERTIES, but still be able to link them to their respective parents.

Because I need to be able to make a call to the database to get all BUILDINGS, regardless of CITY. But also get all PROPERTIES in a specific BUILDING, for example.

Comment: A city will probably contain a lot of buildings. A single MongoDB record is limited in size. You probably *don't* want an array of buildings in your city table. Also, as you mention, it would make querying for only buildings difficult.

Comment: MongoDB is a document database, i.e. it is good for unstructured data. However, your data sounds very much structured, you have CITIES, BUILDINGS and PROPERTIES, probably even types of properties. MongoDB is probably not a good fit.